# Android activity loads wrong layout

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, android-intent

I copied a `.java` class and `.xml` layout.  I thought I renamed everything in order to create a new class, but the new class is loading the old layout when I start a new Intent.  Am I missing someplace where I need to enter the name of the new layout file I have created from a copy of another class' layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I missed this line:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.xxx)
```

This should do it!

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have not set the launcher activity in manifest then you have to specify which Activity starts first
2. If you have set old XMl in   `setContentView(R.layout.xxx)` then this loads old layout so check for proper xml.

Answer (score 0):

After trying the other answers, try checking the following attribute on your layout element:

```
tools:context=".SignUpActivity">
```

That was it for me.